# Iterating through files in folder via FileSystemObject

Tags: vba, excel

Ok, so I consider myself an Excel VBA expert (even though I've not done much with it for a while) but I'm stumped on this one - that obviously means it is something extremely simple which I've overlooked due to my arrogance :D

I'm using a FileSystemObject assigned to a global variable (called "myFSO" - original, I know...) and using two other global variables - xFolder and xFile - to iterate through all the files within a folder, and perform actions on each file within the folder.

This is the code:

```
Global myFSO As FileSystemObject
Global xFolder As Scripting.Folder
Global xFile As Scripting.File

Public Sub GetData()

Set bgd = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BGD")
Set myFSO = New FileSystemObject
Set xFolder = myFSO.GetFolder(bgd.Range("C4").Value)

For Each xFile In xFolder.Files
          <do stuff here>
Next xFile

End Sub
```

So, when I step through the code, I can see that the xFolder is being assigned correctly. If I add a Watch or insert

```
Debug.Print xFolder.Files.Count
```

into the code, it returns the correct file count, so everything seems to be setup fine to go into the For loop and do what it needs to do.

Once I step past the For Each... statement line however the code just runs to the end of the routine, completely missing out the whole of the code nested within the For Each... Next code. It doesn't even go to the "Next xFile" line. If I modify the loop to

```
For i = 1 to xFolder.Files.Count
```

and do the process that way, it works OK. So, it's not a matter of life-and-death since I can do what I want to do, I just wanted to know if anyone could tell why the "For Each" method hasn't worked.

Comment: can you post your code inside your `For Each xFile In xFolder.Files` , when I'm testing it with `bgd.Range("D" & i).Value = xFile.Name` it shows me all my file names in column "D".

Comment: Just irritated why did you declare these variables as `global` at least for `Global xFile As Scripting.File` it doesn't make any sense to have this `global`?

Comment: What are your error settings? If it goes directly to the `End Sub` it probably means that there is an error generated that is masked by the settings. Check the Err object.

Comment: @peh - no reason why they're global to be honest, usually I use these same variable names in much larger projects where the variables are used outside of a single routine... I guess I just did that as force of habit :)

Comment: @VincentG - there are no error handling in the code, and the general idea is one that I've used 100s of times successfully in the past. If I add an error handler, it doesn't get called, suggesting there's no actual error

Comment: @ShaiRado the code within the script doesn't seem to make a difference - I've tried it with "Debug.Print 1" on each iteration but it still doesn't work even with that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a working minimal example:

1. Create a new file
2. Reference the Microsoft scripting Runtime
3. Create a sheet named `BGD` and write an existing path into `C4` e.g. `C:\Windows`
4. Paste the code below into a module and run it

This lists the path and all filenames in the debug window.

```
Public Sub GetData()
    Dim bgd As Worksheet
    Dim myFSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim xFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim xFile As Scripting.File


    Set bgd = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BGD")
    Set myFSO = New FileSystemObject
    Set xFolder = myFSO.GetFolder(bgd.Range("C4").Value)

    Debug.Print xFolder.Path
    For Each xFile In xFolder.Files
        Debug.Print xFile.Name
    Next xFile

End Sub
```

If you need the variables locally then declare them locally instead of global. Anything else is very bad practice and leads into errors.

Comment: Thanks @Peh - you're absolutely right on the subject of global variables, it's just that I've used those variables out of necessity as Globals in other instances so many times I just end up typing them out naturally like that!

Comment: Your post was very helpful in another sense - when testing the code on a different folder it works as expected, so it must be something about the (network) folder I was trying to access - possibly a case of security/folder permissions or so on.

Comment: Therefore I always start with a minimal example as simple as possible. If it works you are on the right track and can go more into detail. If it fails you immediately found your issue. Otherwise you run into analyzing the details and end up with something fundamental being wrong after several hours of searching if you start debugging from the wrong side.

Comment: I didn't think to change the folder tbh, since the variable xFolder was assigning properly, but again you're absolutely spot-on, I should've thought to test it. Still, nevermind, I finally joined StackOverflow on the back of this query after years of just being a visitor so one good thing has come of it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok - turns out the issue was actually with the folder and not the code. As pointed out by @Peh, I should have tested the code with another folder, as well as testing variations of the code itself. When using another folder, the `For Each` code worked fine. As stated in the OP, I just used `For i = 1 to xFolder.Files.Count` rather than `For Each` and got the result I needed, but I prefer the object-led approach of `For Each` rather than using an integer/long variable to go through the item count, and wanted to know why that method wasn't working.

To get the `For Each` code working, I copied the desired files to a different folder and it worked perfectly well. As the original folder was a network location, there was possibly some folder permissions or security setting preventing me from using the code I wanted to.

Answer (score -1):

I  think you want to list all files in all folders and all sub-folders. Check out this link.

http://www.learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2011/11/how-to-get-list-of-all-files-in-a-folder-and-sub-folders/

Download the file; that's the way to go. Once all paths and all file names are listed in your Excel worksheet, you can do all kinds of comparisons, manipulations, and the like.

```
 Sub GetFilesInFolder(SourceFolderName As String)  

    '--- For Example:Folder Name= "D:\Folder Name\"  

    Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject  
    Dim SourceFolder As Scripting.folder, SubFolder As Scripting.folder  
    Dim FileItem As Scripting.File  

        Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject  
        Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)  

        '--- This is for displaying, whereever you want can be configured  

        r = 14  
        For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files  
            Cells(r, 2).Formula = r - 13  
            Cells(r, 3).Formula = FileItem.Name  
            Cells(r, 4).Formula = FileItem.Path  
            Cells(r, 5).Formula = FileItem.Size  
            Cells(r, 6).Formula = FileItem.Type  
            Cells(r, 7).Formula = FileItem.DateLastModified  
            Cells(r, 8).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & FileItem.Path & """,""" & "Click Here to Open" & """)"  

            r = r + 1   ' next row number  
        Next FileItem  

        Set FileItem = Nothing  
        Set SourceFolder = Nothing  
        Set FSO = Nothing  
    End Sub  


Sub GetFilesInFolder(SourceFolderName As String, Subfolders As Boolean)  

'--- For Example:Folder Name= "D:\Folder Name\" and Flag as Yes or No  

Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject  
Dim SourceFolder As Scripting.folder, SubFolder As Scripting.folder  
Dim FileItem As Scripting.File  
'Dim r As Long  
    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject  
    Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)  

    '--- This is for displaying, whereever you want can be configured  

    r = 14  
    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files  
        Cells(r, 2).Formula = r - 13  
        Cells(r, 3).Formula = FileItem.Name  
        Cells(r, 4).Formula = FileItem.Path  
        Cells(r, 5).Formula = FileItem.Size  
        Cells(r, 6).Formula = FileItem.Type  
        Cells(r, 7).Formula = FileItem.DateLastModified  
        Cells(r, 8).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & FileItem.Path & """,""" & "Click Here to Open" & """)"  

        r = r + 1   ' next row number  
    Next FileItem  

    '--- This is the Function to go each and Every Folder and get the Files. This is a Nested-Function Calling.  

    If Subfolders = True Then  
        For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.Subfolders  
            ListFilesInFolder SubFolder.Path, True  
        Next SubFolder  
    End If  

    Set FileItem = Nothing  
    Set SourceFolder = Nothing  
    Set FSO = Nothing  
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @ryguy72, I'm not looking to list the folder contents; the code nested within the For Each statement opens the files and performs actions on the worksheets within those files. Really, it was not the nested code that was the issue, it was a specific instance of this For Each loop not working. Turns out that it is probably to do with the folder's security settings or permissions, as another folder worked fine with the same code.