# Error when importing files from sharepoint

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and this forum has been very helpful to me. I follow the threads posted on this forum to find answers to my questions and I would like to thank you all for providing awesome solutions.

I am currently working on generating a summarysheet from the excel files posted on SharePoint. I have mapped the sharepoint as a network drive. I am trying to open all files from sharepoint folder one after another, copy the required data from different tabs, paste it to summary sheet and close the file. When I try to run the code, it gives me a run time error 52 as 'bad file name or number'.

I have pasted the part of my code here. Any kind of help in this matter is really appreciated.

Thank you,
Pranav

```
Option Explicit
Sub GenerateSummary()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim Directory As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim SummarySheet As Workbook

Set SummarySheet = Workbooks.Add

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Please select a folder"
    .Show
    .AllowMultiSelect = False

    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("You did not select a folder")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Directory = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

MyFile = Dir(Directory & "*.xlsx")

Do While MyFile <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (Directory & MyFile)
    Sheets(Array(1, 2)).Select
    Sheets(1).Activate
    Sheets(Array(1, 2)).Copy Before:=SummarySheet.Sheets(1)
    ' Other statistics are calculated and operations are performed here

    MyFile = Dir()
    ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It gives you this error and an option to hit the "Debug" button. When you do so, which line is highlighted?

Comment: @JNevill 
MyFile = Dir(Directory & "*.xlsx") this line gets highlighted on error

Comment: Are you choosing a local directory or one on a server? Do you have authority to see/read the files in that directory? Are there any special characters in the file names in that folder? DIR can be kind of picky.

Comment: I am choosing local directory. I can read even edit those files. File names contain parentheses "()" and periods(.) . Is that causing an error when selecting a file ?

I tried to download the files and tried access those without changing names. The code worked fine that time.

Comment: Probably the Parentheses. Dir is old school and it's picky. Can you try renaming or pointing at a different directory just to see if your code works, that would narrow it down.

Comment: Yes. I tried changing the directory. Code works fine with other path directory

Comment: @JNevill I am sorry. I kind of misunderstood you. with directory, I was assuming path directory like "C:\" etc and not the Dir() function. If possibly you know any, can you please mention, an alternative directory to Dir()? Thank you.

Comment: [Check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367671/vba-excel-iterating-through-files-in-folder-via-filesystemobject/43369428) where they use the FSO library. I think that will do what you need.

Comment: @JNevill Thank you for sharing the thread. I was trying different ways and come up with something. Since it's a mapped network drive, I provided the actual path in With loop instead of '.SelectedItems(1) query.
Now code runs fine but gives error randomly Error 1004: File could not be found. 
All files are there. Sometimes it picks up the file and sometimes gives an error

Comment: Ok. So I tried a lot of different ways, went through internet to fix that error but it didn't help me. Finally, I repaired my MS Office and then the code worked fine after that.
Thank you very much @JNevill for all help.