# Does Dir have a limit of size?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder with 500,000 .xml files. 
I am scanning it like this:

```
filePath = Dir(srcPath & "\*.xml")
Do While Len(filePath) > 0

    'do something with the file
    filePath = Dir
Loop
```

This works fine for ~66,000 files, but then it fails on line:

```
filePath = Dir
```

... with a very generic message: `Invalid procedure call or argument`.
I've searched on the web, and I can't find anything similar (this error usually appears at the very beginning, not after 66,000 success).

The only thing I can think about is that `Dir` has a limit and over a certain number of elements, it's unable to go further and the exception is not handled so a very generic message is raised - but I'm not convinced at all of this explanation.

Does anyone have any idea?

P.s. in the code "`'do something with the file`", I'm calling another function but it's not using `=Dir()` again, just loading the XML file and reading some information.

Comment: I wonder if this has to do something with the limit for [number of files in a single folder for FAT32](https://superuser.com/a/446284/52365). I would not be terribly surprised if `Dir` has that hardcoded given the time it was written.

Comment: @GSerg, ah, this is a very good tip! The number I've got was slightly more than 66,000 while this one is 65,534, but still it seems the closest bet. I'll try to search more on the subject.

Comment: What line specifically throws "invalid procedure call.."? name of the file?

Comment: @shahkalpesh *"But then it fails on line: `filePath = Dir`"*

Comment: @shahkalpesh the name of the file is `TPK2323_seq_enrichment_42335_ps.xml`, but I don't think it's relevant as all the previous ones were very similar (the only difference among each file name is the ID `42335` which goes from 0 to 500000).

Comment: Interesting. Did you try using `FileSystemObject` instead? What was the result?

Comment: @RyanWildry I did, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43369428/3111149), and it worked. So the problem itself is solved, but I fear the closest answer is the one given by GSerg.

Comment: You did not post the 'do something code where you read the file. Are you closing the file after reading? Just in case the error is coincidentally near the fat32 limit...

Comment: @Jumpgroup I'm just loading the XML document into a local `MSXML` instance to read the xml tree, but I'm just [loading it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms762722(v%3Dvs.85)), not opening for modification, hence it doesn't need to be closed.