# Handling Special Character in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, unicode, filenames

I´m using a code in VBA (Excel file) to read all the folders in a path and accessing such folders.
The program is crashing with error 53: File not found.

After some debug I realized that this happens when the folder name has special character (like 'é' or 'ó').
Apparently when forming a string with such characters the VBA replaces then by other things (like '´o'), this is leading to the subsequent crash because a folder with such modified name does not exist.
Is there any way to work this around?

```vb
Function GetFoldersIn(Folder As String) As Collection
  Dim F As String
  Set GetFoldersIn = New Collection
  F = Dir(Folder & "\*", vbDirectory)
  Do While F <> ""
    If (Right(F, 4) <> ".doc" And Right(F, 4) <> ".pdf") Then
        c = Folder + "\" + F
        a = GetAttr(c)
        b = vbDirectory
        If a And b Then GetFoldersIn.Add F
    End If
    F = Dir 'here is where the name of the folder is messed !!!!
  Loop
End Function
```

---

@userMT, Thanks for the reply! With the example you sent I went far. Now I'm stuck in another issue. I improved the code to perform a recursive search at the folder. It's working fine for small folders, i.e., folders with approximately fifty folders within (including all levels).

When I tried it in a quite big directory I have (approx. 3000 folders), I got this error:

> Run-time error Method ‘Count’ of object ‘IFolderCollection’ failed.

After clicking “debug” on the error window, I watched the variable `xFolder.SubFolders.Count`, this is what I saw:

> <Application-defined or object-defined error>.

Please note that the error appeared even after the code running successfully through several folders.

```vb
Function GetFoldersIn(Path As String) As Collection
    'Localiza todas
    Dim myFSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim xFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim xSubFolder As Scripting.Folder
    
    Set GetFoldersIn = New Collection
    Set myFSO = New FileSystemObject
    Set xFolder = myFSO.GetFolder(Path)
    
    GetFoldersIn.Add Path
    If xFolder.SubFolders.Count <> 0 Then 'Error is in this line !!!!!!!!!!
        For Each SubFolder In xFolder.SubFolders
            Set aux = GetFoldersIn(SubFolder.Path)
            For Each Item In aux
                GetFoldersIn.Add Item
            Next Item
        Next SubFolder
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried the FilesystemObject for this (there is a usage example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367671/iterating-through-files-in-folder-via-filesystemobject)?

Comment: In testing I don't see any problem with that code.

Comment: @TimWilliams, maybe the name of your folders have no special character. Please test it with a folder with “ó” for example).

Comment: When testing I copy-pasted both of those characters from your question into folder names and saw no problems in running the code.