# Excel to PDF conversion using VBA failing after one iteration

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am trying to use VBA to loop over all of the excel files in a folder and convert them to pdf. The first interation works perfectly, does the conversion as expected but then after the first one has completed.
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCTBo.png) and then sends and error saying that a file already exists with that name. I have tried different files but this is a consistent issue.

```
Sub ConvertExcelToPDF()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FilePath As String


    Dim NewFilePath As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim TotalFiles As Integer
    Dim ProcessedFiles As Integer
    
    ' Set the folder path where the Excel files are located
    FolderPath = "C:\path\to\file\"
    
    
    ' Get the first Excel file in the folder
    
    ' Reset the FileName to get the first Excel file again
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xlsx")
    
    ' Initialize the count of processed files
    ProcessedFiles = 0
    
    ' Loop through all Excel files in the folder
    Do While FileName <> ""
        ' Build the full file path
        FilePath = FolderPath & FileName
        
        ' Build the new file path for the PDF
        NewFilePath = Replace(FilePath, ".xlsx", ".pdf", , , vbTextCompare)
        
        ' Check if the PDF file already exists
        ' EDIT: The issue seems to be caused by this If FileExists
        If FileExists(NewFilePath) Then
            MsgBox "A PDF file with the same name already exists: " & NewFilePath & ". Skipping conversion."
        Else
            ' Open the Excel file
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
            
            ' Check if the workbook has at least one sheet
            If wb.Sheets.Count > 0 Then
                ' Get the first sheet in the workbook
                Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
                
                ' Save the first sheet as PDF
                ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=NewFilePath
                
                ' Close the Excel file
                wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
                Set wb = Nothing
                
                ' Increment the count of processed files
                ProcessedFiles = ProcessedFiles + 1
                
                ' Display a message indicating the file processed
                MsgBox "PDF generated for file: " & FileName
            Else
                MsgBox "The workbook does not contain any sheets. Skipping conversion."
                wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
                Set wb = Nothing
            End If
        End If
        
        ' Reset the FileName to get the next Excel file in the folder
        FileName = Dir
    Loop
    
    Exit Sub
    
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description
    If Not wb Is Nothing Then
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If
    Set wb = Nothing
    Resume Next
End Sub

Function FileExists(FilePath As String) As Boolean
    FileExists = (Dir(FilePath) <> "")
End Function
```

I have put in various counters in to try and debug the issue but no luck. I am quite new to VBA having mainly used R (their conversion tools are not platform-independent).

EDIT: Removed some of the garbage in the reprex. The issue seems to be caused by the If(FileExists... which is there to stop accidentally overwriting existing files.

Comment: Remove the error handler (just comment out the `On Error Goto ErrorHandler`-Line) and check which statement issues the error. Or use the debugger and execute the code step by step (use [F8]) to see where it fails.

Comment: `FileName = Dir` will not yield a proper file name - will it. I don't see you incrementing/changing your fileName inside the loop which will lead to either the same FileName or whatever `FileName = Dir` returns as FileName

Comment: I have found that the file counter works with that and other people have used FileName=Dir (or equivalent) to get the next file. The debugger picks out that line as the point where it fails. Is there an argument missing?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function - based on this you have to do `Dir()` - Small tip for the future: If you are working with "new" functions/methods/properties or whatever else, it might be beneficial to look up the documentation of said new thing you are using.

Comment: Iterating with `Dir()` is in my opinion quite unintuitive - When I am working with folders/files I usually use the FileSystemObject (which works with Collections this makes iterating way more intuitive) It also has the added benefit, that you can easily Delete/Manipulate files/folders. - Just something to keep in mind for the future

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is that, while executing the `Dir`-Loop, you are issuing another `Dir`-command in `FileExists`.

The `Dir`-command works like this:
First you issue a `Dir`-command with a parameter giving a file pattern. You do it with `Dir(FolderPath & "*.xlsx")`, asking for any file with the extension `xlsx` in that specific folder. The return value is the first file matching that pattern.

Every following call to `Dir` without parameter will return the next matching file until there is no more file left.

But as soon as you issue another `Dir`-command with parameter, you will break that loop - and initiate a new one. In your case, you issue a `Dir` in the `FileExists`-routine, and this will destroy the loop that lists all Excel files. Because of that, the `Dir` command (without parameter) at the end of the loop will always return the empty string and your loop exits after the first file.

Workarounds:
Either save the list of files during your first loop (where you count the files) into an array and loop over that array.
Or, use the `FileSystemObject` instead of the Dir command, see for example [Iterating through files in folder via FileSystemObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367671/iterating-through-files-in-folder-via-filesystemobject)